# Google app engine python cron: What is the testcron.py doing in the app.yaml file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

Here's a sample code for gae python cron job.

app.yaml

```
- url: /testcron
  script: testcron.py
  login: admin

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: testcron
  url: /testcron
  schedule: every 12 hours
```

main.py

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.request.write('hello')

class TestCronHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info('hello')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/testcron',TestCronHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Okay, so I've noticed that you do not need `script: testcron.py` in the app.yaml file. But if you put it there, it is required to run another application.

So what is the purpose of that? I mean you can run it in TestCronHandler.
What is the difference between running in main.app handler and running in testcron.py? (It seems like you need to run another app with testcron.py)

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you mean by

> if you put it there, it is required to run another application

and

> It seems like you need to run another app with testcron.py

If you mean you need to define another `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication` inside `taskcron.py` then yes, that is true but it looks like you don't have the `testcron.py` file at all and your `main.py` is handling requests to `/testcron` so your `app.yaml` could look as simple as:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

It's up to you whether you want to separate (for better code organization?) cron requests/handlers into a separate file but note that if you have a file called taskcron.**py** it would need to appear in `app.yaml` as "script: taskcron.**app**".

Also, an important security note, if you want to make sure that regular users cannot access your cron task URLs then you should definitely move your cron task handlers into a separate file and keep the `login: admin` line below `script: testcron.app` inside `app.yaml`.